# Why is not my webhook calling my backend?

Tags: c#, webhooks

I have an application in C# .NET Core and I am using PAGARME as payment solution (a payment gateway brazilian company) and I have configured web hooks, for example, when cards are created.

As I am developing on localhost, I am using NGROK to expose my application. I have configured my CORS to receive any origin, method and header.

The method that I have created to receive the webhook is working when calling it by postman, but the webhooks are not arriving and accessing my endpoint.

Only one more information: If i use postman to call this method it is working! It is not working from the pagarme system.

Could you tell me if I did something wrong?

My CORS configurations:

[image: My CORS configurations]

NGROK configuration:

[image: NGROK configuration]

The method I have created to receive the webhook. The method is not implemented, it is only a test:

[image: The method i have created to receive the webhook. The method is not implemented, it is only a test]

That is the configuration of webhook on Pagarme system. Look that the url is the same of NGROK with the rest of the endpoint:

[image: That is the configuration of webhook on Pagarme system. Look that the url is the same of NGROK with the rest of the endpoint]

Comment: Please include your configuration in-line with your question. Linking to an external site, especially images, does not lend itself well to getting your question answered. 

See here for help formatting your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting